# Array data issue Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5

I have an array issue in here and I'm spending a lot of time with.
I get a list of  array like this form

```
array:4 [

0 => array:20 [▼
"id" => 58
"id_business" => 
"id_branch" => 
"affected_branches" => " " ▶"
"name" => ""
"banner" => ""
"description" => ""
"url" => 
"start_date" => ""
"end_date" => ""
"nr_pages" => 4
"nr_products" => 0
"type" => "global"
"views" => 24
"visible" => "yes"
"delete" => "no"
"user_create_id" => 
"user_modify_id" => 
"created_at" => ""
"updated_at" => "2017-06-07 14:19:23"]
]
```

by the following code

```
  $data = Offers::whereIn('id_business', $business_id_array)
                    ->where([
                       'visible' => 'yes',
                       'delete' => 'no'
                     ])
                     ->where('end_date', '>=', date('Y-m-d h:m:i'))
                    ->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get()
                    ->toArray();
```

when i try to make a foreach loop for all arrays that came, in this case 4, it does not return me 4 values, but only one.
The loop is:

```
 foreach ($data as $key => $slide)
                {
                    $offers = DB::select('SELECT o.`id`... WHERE o.`id` = ?',[$slide['id']]);

                }

                return view('...', ['offers' => $offers]);
            }
```

I pass this values in query to get the id of each of arrays

```
o.`id` = ?',[$slide['id']]
```

PS: PLS Help Me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overwriting `$offers` value with each iteration, so change your code to:

```
$offers = [];
foreach ($data as $key => $slide) {
    $offers[] = DB::select...
}
```

Comment: Hmm i think is it stuck at foreach because when I dd($slide); i get only the first value.

Comment: @User154584 you'll always get first value in the loop if you'll use `dd()` inside the loop. Just use `dd($offers)` after the loop and you'll see an array of offers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to  change $offres in to array

```
$offers = array();
foreach ($data as $key => $slide)
{
    $offers[] = DB::select('SELECT o.`id`... WHERE o.`id` = ?',[$slide['id']]);

}

return view('...', ['offers' => $offers]);
```

Comment: Hmm i think is it stuck at foreach because when I dd($slide); i get only the first value.

Comment: use `dd($slide)` after `foreach` loop completed